# Trying to install express js

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to install express.js to a new project but it's not working. Even though it gives me the version of express that I have, it's not listed in the dependencies and it doesn't work when I try to import it, giving a 'Module not found' error.

I tried to install it in vs code terminal. I was hoping for it to be listed as a dependency but it hasn't been.

`npm install express` this is what I wrote.

This is what it's saying

```
npm WARN config global --global --local are deprecated. Use --location=global instead.

changed 64 packages in 10m

12 packages are looking for funding
  run npm fund for details

still not in the dependencies list
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the global npm location to `user`

```
$ npm config set location=user
```

If above didn't work, you have to manually override the location value in `.npmrc`.

To get the location of `.npmrc` file,

```
$ npm config get userconfig
```

This returns the file path

More on [NPM Doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-config#location)

Comment: I checked the document, but it doesn't really say anything on what I should do. I think the problem is I've installed and used node modules before and it might have something to do with that. Because a node modules file has not been generated in my current directory. I want to have a node modules directory in my new project but every time i run "npm install" it doesn't add it or a package_lock.json file. what can i do?